# How to perform batch computation in python by adding processes as soon as cores become free?

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

Bash has the function "wait -n" which can be used in a relatively trivial way to halt subsequent execution of child processes until a certain number of processor cores have been made available. E.g. I can do the following,

```
for IJOB in IJOBRANGE;
do

    ./func.x ${IJOB}

    # checking the number of background processes
    # and halting the execution accordingly

    bground=( $(jobs -p) );

    if (( ${#bground[@]} >= CORES )); then
        wait -n
    fi

done || exit 1
```

This snippet can batch execute an arbitrary C process "func.x" with varying arguments and always maintains a fixed number of parallel instances of the child processes, set to the value "CORES".

I was wondering if something similar could be done with a python script and
python child processes (or functions). Currently, I define a python function, set up an one dimensional parameter array and use the the Pool routine from the python multiprocessing module to parallel compute the function over the parameter array. The pool functions perform a set number (# of CPU CORES in the following example) of evaluation of my function and waits until all the instances of the spawned processes have concluded before moving to the next batch.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def func(x):

    # some computation with x

def main(j):

    # setting the parameter array
    xarray = range(j)

    pool = mp.Pool()
    pool.map(func,xarray)
```

I would like to know if it is possible to modify this snippet in order to always perform a fixed number of parallel computation of my subroutine, i.e. add another process as soon as one of the child processes have been finished. All the "func" processes here are supposed to be independent and the order of execution does not matter either. I am new to the python way and it would be really great to have some helpful perspectives.

Comment: Could you clarify please ? I don't really get what you're trying to do. Doesn't your code already do what you want (i.e. "perform a fixed number of parallel computations") ?

Comment: I am sorry if the message was not clear. In case of asymmetrical work load this can get slightly complicated. Let's say I have 40 cores and therefore the multiprocessing Pool spliced up my parameter array into batches of 40. However for each set, it will wait until all of these 40 function calls have been completed. Ideally, I would like to have a solution which would for example add 2 further processes once 2 of the current batch finishes up. Was that clear? Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: That was clearer, thanks ! I've played with the module a bit and it seems it doesn't wait for all tasks to be complete to start a new one. I'll post some example code as an answer since it's hard to do in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following our discussion in the comments, here's some test code adapted from yours that shows `Pool`s don't wait for all parallel tasks to complete before assigning a new one to available workers:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from time import sleep, time


def func(x):
    """sleeps for x seconds"""
    name = mp.current_process().name
    print("{} {}: sleep {}".format(time(), name, x))
    sleep(x)
    print("{} {}: done sleeping".format(time(), name))


def main():

    # A pool of two processes, for the sake of simplicity
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=2)
    # Here's how that works out visually:
    #
    #    0s        1s       2s        3s
    # P1 [sleep(1)][     sleep(2)     ]
    # P2 [     sleep(2)     ][sleep(1)]
    sleeps = [1, 2, 2, 1]
    pool.map(func, sleeps)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Running this code gives (timestamps simplified for clarity):

```
$ python3 mp.py 
0s: ForkPoolWorker-1: sleep 1
0s: ForkPoolWorker-2: sleep 2
1s: ForkPoolWorker-1: done sleeping
1s: ForkPoolWorker-1: sleep 2
2s: ForkPoolWorker-2: done sleeping
2s: ForkPoolWorker-2: sleep 1
3s: ForkPoolWorker-1: done sleeping
3s: ForkPoolWorker-2: done sleeping
```

We can see that the first process doesn't wait for the second process to complete its first task before starting its second task.

So I guess that should answer the point you were raising, hope I've understood you clearly.

Comment: Really good idea, I was testing it out myself a bit (but in a less good way than you) and came to the same conclusion. My testing included timing the imap with different chunk sizes. Yours is much more to the point though.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. I thought about chunk sizes too, but it seems the defaults are sane and there wasn't any fiddling to do with the parameters. That's what I like about Python: simple and to the point :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a clean example, I could not appreciate it more. I had noticed a behavior in my original computation where at times the core usage sunk to a fraction of the batch count with plenty of batches remaining. I was curious as to why that might have been happening and my limited knowledge of the module led me to misconstrue its scope. Thanks again, for clarifying the confusion.